# create a python list with fixed steps but no fixed limits

Tags: python, list, range

I have a question about `list`.  My list needs to be around a midpoint with minimum of 1, and it needs 6 integer steps (+/-) evenly around the midpoint, with step of 1. There will be 7 digits (midpoint + 6 steps) in the list.

e.g.,`if mid = 10`, then the `list = [7,8,9,**10**,11,12,13]`. 3 steps above 10 and 3 steps below 10.
But `if mid = 3`, the digits then can't distribute evenly with 3 steps above and under the midpoint, because the minimum is 1. To ensure 7 items in the list, 4 steps above 3 and 2 steps under 3. Thus, `[1,2,**3**,4,5,6,7]`. If the `mid=2`, 5 steps above 2 and 1 step under 2. The list is still `[1,**2**,3,4,5,6,7]`.
Here is my code:

```
def gain_range(mid):

    gainLower_list = list(range(1, mid)) #items under the midpoint
    gainUpper_list = list(range(mid, n)) #items above the midpoint, hence I can combine the two lists later
    if mid >= 4:
       n = mid + 3
    elif mid >= 3:
       n = mid + 4
    elif mid >= 2:
       n = mid + 5
    elif mid >= 1:
       n = mid + 6        

gain_range(3)
```

but this codes gives an error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment

How should I fix this? And is there more elegant way to create this list with fixed steps, rather than fixed limits?

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. Nether of your examples are +/- 6 steps around the midpoint.

Comment: Under what conditions do you not simply want `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`? The `**`s in `[1,2,**3**,4,5,6,7]` mean nothing so `[1,2,**3**,4,5,6,7]` and `[1,2,3,**4**,5,6,7]` are the same.

Comment: You need better specifications. Any number of solution, many of which probably arent what youre looking for would fit the spec you provided. For example: if `mid=100` does that mean `[1,2,3....**100**,101,102,103]`. and if so, how many digits after the `mid` do you want? Or are you suggesting and evenly distributed 6 digits surrounding the `mid` with a min of 1?

Comment: @DYZ I'm sorry about my confusing wording. English is not my first language. I mean 6 steps around the midpoint in total, it has some items larger than the midpoint, some smaller, and the list contains 7 items including the midpoint. If that is more clear?

Comment: @Verbal_Kint My mistake, forgot an important specification. The step size is 1, and there are 6 steps around the midpoint.

Comment: Do you still insist that the min should be 1?

Comment: @DYZ Yes, I want the min to be 1. Because the step size is 1, this limitation will affect the list only if the `midpoint <4`, in the case, if I want 3 steps under from the midpoint, the smallest number is 0, which I don't want. If `midpoint > 3`, the digits can be distributed evenly with 3 steps above and under the midpoint.

Comment: what's wrong with @Stephen_Raush answer? It seems to fit all your specifications and is short and sweet

Comment: The min of `[7,8,9,10,11,12,13]` is not 1. Your specs are still inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only decision needed is for the starting value which must be >= 1, so calculate that first, then just return a `list` from `range`:

**Code:**

```
def gain_range(mid):
    start = max(1, mid - 3)
    return list(range(start, start+7))
```

**Test Code:**

```
print(gain_range(3))
print(gain_range(4))
print(gain_range(5))
```

**Results:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: given the specs, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Just addressing the error here: you use the variable `n` in your code before you have declared it.

```
def gain_range(mid):

    gainLower_list = list(range(1, mid))
    gainUpper_list = list(range(mid, n))  # use n here but is hasnt been declared and assigned a value
    if mid >= 4:
       n = mid + 3
    elif mid >= 3:
       n = mid + 4
    elif mid >= 2:
       n = mid + 5
    elif mid >= 1:
       n = mid + 6
```

You need to assign a value to `n` before then...

However, if you just want 6 evenly distributed, consecutive digits surrounding `mid` with a minimum of 1 then the answer above mine (Steven Rausch) should do the trick